# Processing data set into 30 minute values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a data set in the following format -

```
ID  START_TIME              END_TIME                VAL

1   30-APR-2018 00:00:00    01-MAY-2018 00:00:00    423
2   01-MAY-2018 00:00:00    01-MAY-2018 17:15:00    455
3   01-MAY-2018 17:15:00    03-MAY-2018 00:00:00    455
```

> Expected Output -

This data set should be broken down into 30 min interval values, however if there are records which are not at '00' or '30' minute point then they should be considered as part of this process (as shown for record with START_TIME/END_TIME = '17:15:00')

```
ID  START_TIME              END_TIME                VAL

1   30-APR-2018 00:00:00    30-APR-2018 00:30:00    423
1   30-APR-2018 00:30:00    30-APR-2018 01:00:00    423
1   30-APR-2018 01:00:00    30-APR-2018 01:30:00    423
..
..
..

1   30-APR-2018 23:00:00    30-APR-2018 23:30:00    423
1   30-APR-2018 23:30:00    01-MAY-2018 00:00:00    423
2   01-MAY-2018 00:00:00    01-MAY-2018 00:30:00    455
2   01-MAY-2018 00:30:00    01-MAY-2018 01:00:00    455
..
..
..
..
2   01-MAY-2018 16:30:00    01-MAY-2018 17:00:00    455
2   01-MAY-2018 17:00:00    01-MAY-2018 17:15:00    455
3   01-MAY-2018 17:15:00    03-MAY-2018 17:30:00    455
3   01-MAY-2018 17:30:00    03-MAY-2018 18:00:00    455
..
..
..
3   02-MAY-2018 23:00:00    02-MAY-2018 23:30:00    455
3   02-MAY-2018 23:30:00    03-MAY-2018 00:00:00    455
```

What I have tried so far -

```
CREATE TABLE TESTT
( 
    ID NUMBER(8,3),
    START_TIME DATE,
    END_TIME DATE,
    VAL NUMBER(8,3)
);

INSERT INTO TESTT VALUES (1, TO_DATE('30-APR-2018 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),  TO_DATE('01-MAY-2018 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 423);
INSERT INTO TESTT VALUES (2, TO_DATE('01-MAY-2018 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),  TO_DATE('01-MAY-2018 17:15:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 455);
INSERT INTO TESTT VALUES (3, TO_DATE('01-MAY-2018 17:15:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),  TO_DATE('03-MAY-2018 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 455);
COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE TESTT_OUTPUT AS
SELECT * FROM TESTT WHERE 1=2;

CREATE SEQUENCE TESTT_SEQ MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE NOORDER NOCYCLE NOPARTITION;


BEGIN

FOR R IN (SELECT * FROM TESTT)
LOOP
    INSERT INTO TESTT_OUTPUT(id, START_TIME, END_TIME, VAL)
    SELECT TESTT_SEQ.nextval, R.START_TIME + (LEVEL - 1)/48 AS START_TIME, R.START_TIME + LEVEL/48 AS END_TIME, R.VAL FROM
    DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ROUND((R.END_TIME - R.START_TIME)*48);

    COMMIT;
END LOOP;

END;
/


SELECT * FROM TESTT_OUTPUT;




1   30-APR-2018 00:00:00    30-APR-2018 00:30:00    423
2   30-APR-2018 00:30:00    30-APR-2018 01:00:00    423
3   30-APR-2018 01:00:00    30-APR-2018 01:30:00    423
..
..
..
47  30-APR-2018 23:00:00    30-APR-2018 23:30:00    423
48  30-APR-2018 23:30:00    01-MAY-2018 00:00:00    423
49  01-MAY-2018 00:00:00    01-MAY-2018 00:30:00    455
50  01-MAY-2018 00:30:00    01-MAY-2018 01:00:00    455
..
..
..
82  01-MAY-2018 16:30:00    01-MAY-2018 17:00:00    455
83  01-MAY-2018 17:00:00    01-MAY-2018 17:30:00    455
84  01-MAY-2018 17:15:00    01-MAY-2018 17:45:00    455
85  01-MAY-2018 17:45:00    01-MAY-2018 18:15:00    455
86  01-MAY-2018 18:15:00    01-MAY-2018 18:45:00    455
87  01-MAY-2018 18:45:00    01-MAY-2018 19:15:00    455
..
..
..
141 02-MAY-2018 21:45:00    02-MAY-2018 22:15:00    455
142 02-MAY-2018 22:15:00    02-MAY-2018 22:45:00    455
143 02-MAY-2018 22:45:00    02-MAY-2018 23:15:00    455
144 02-MAY-2018 23:15:00    02-MAY-2018 23:45:00    455
145 02-MAY-2018 23:45:00    03-MAY-2018 00:15:00    455
```

With this approach any data with the minute value other than '00' or '30' will still be processed the same way by adding 30 mins to it and the final result does not have the point in time data for '00' or '30' minute value.

Hope this makes sense.

Any inputs on how to translate the data in the expected format will be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems rather inelegant, but this;

```
select id,
  greatest(start_time,
    adj_start_time + numtodsinterval(30 * (level - 1), 'MINUTE')) as start_time,
  least(end_time,
    adj_start_time + numtodsinterval(30 * level, 'MINUTE')) as end_time
from (
  select id,
    start_time,
    end_time,
    trunc(start_time, 'HH')
      + numtodsinterval(
          case when extract(minute from cast(start_time as timestamp)) < 30 then 0
               else 30
          end, 'MINUTE') as adj_start_time
  from testt
)
connect by level <= ceil((end_time - start_time - 1/86400) / (30/1440))
and prior id = id
and prior dbms_random.value is not null
order by id, start_time;
```

seems to get the result you want, generating 145 rows:

```
        ID START_TIME          END_TIME           
---------- ------------------- -------------------
         1 2018-04-30 00:00:00 2018-04-30 00:30:00
         1 2018-04-30 00:30:00 2018-04-30 01:00:00
         1 2018-04-30 01:00:00 2018-04-30 01:30:00
...
         1 2018-04-30 22:30:00 2018-04-30 23:00:00
         1 2018-04-30 23:00:00 2018-04-30 23:30:00
         1 2018-04-30 23:30:00 2018-05-01 00:00:00
         2 2018-05-01 00:00:00 2018-05-01 00:30:00
         2 2018-05-01 00:30:00 2018-05-01 01:00:00
         2 2018-05-01 01:00:00 2018-05-01 01:30:00
...
         2 2018-05-01 16:00:00 2018-05-01 16:30:00
         2 2018-05-01 16:30:00 2018-05-01 17:00:00
         2 2018-05-01 17:00:00 2018-05-01 17:15:00
         3 2018-05-01 17:15:00 2018-05-01 17:30:00
         3 2018-05-01 17:30:00 2018-05-01 18:00:00
         3 2018-05-01 18:00:00 2018-05-01 18:30:00
...
         3 2018-05-02 22:30:00 2018-05-02 23:00:00
         3 2018-05-02 23:00:00 2018-05-02 23:30:00
         3 2018-05-02 23:30:00 2018-05-03 00:00:00
```

The inline view gets the real columns plus the nominal 30-minute window for the start -i.e., for 17:15 it gets 17:00, as `adj_start_time`. The hierarchical query adds 30-minute intervals to that, and uses `least` and `greatest` to get the original start/end time if they are not exactly on the half-hour.

For your insert you can replace the original ID with an analytic `row_number()` rather than using a sequence, and include the `val`:

```
insert into testt_output(id, start_time, end_time, val)
select row_number() over (order by id, level),
  greatest(start_time,
    adj_start_time + numtodsinterval(30 * (level - 1), 'MINUTE')) as start_time,
  least(end_time,
    adj_start_time + numtodsinterval(30 * level, 'MINUTE')) as end_time,
  val
from (
  select id,
    start_time,
    end_time,
    val,
    trunc(start_time, 'HH')
      + numtodsinterval(
          case when extract(minute from cast(start_time as timestamp)) < 30 then 0
               else 30
          end, 'MINUTE') as adj_start_time
  from testt
)
connect by level <= ceil((end_time - start_time - 1/86400) / (30/1440))
and prior id = id
and prior dbms_random.value is not null;

145 rows inserted.

select * from testt_output;

        ID START_TIME          END_TIME                   VAL
---------- ------------------- ------------------- ----------
         1 2018-04-30 00:00:00 2018-04-30 00:30:00        423
         2 2018-04-30 00:30:00 2018-04-30 01:00:00        423
...
        47 2018-04-30 23:00:00 2018-04-30 23:30:00        423
        48 2018-04-30 23:30:00 2018-05-01 00:00:00        423
        49 2018-05-01 00:00:00 2018-05-01 00:30:00        455
        50 2018-05-01 00:30:00 2018-05-01 01:00:00        455
...
        82 2018-05-01 16:30:00 2018-05-01 17:00:00        455
        83 2018-05-01 17:00:00 2018-05-01 17:15:00        455
        84 2018-05-01 17:15:00 2018-05-01 17:30:00        455
        85 2018-05-01 17:30:00 2018-05-01 18:00:00        455
...
       144 2018-05-02 23:00:00 2018-05-02 23:30:00        455
       145 2018-05-02 23:30:00 2018-05-03 00:00:00        455
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e79bd71b915b52d840217fcede729d81).